# Random sampling one element without making it a list in Python

Tags: python, list, random, parent

I've got 4 lists, which are lists on their selves since they contain 3D point coordinates.

**Example**

```
var1 = [[0.09476800262928009, -0.23948000371456146, 0.22791500389575958], 
        [0.015838999301195145, 0.2482910007238388, 0.16062000393867493]]
```

I need to pick a random list one out of these 4, without making this a list on itself.

**I currently doing this with this simple line:**

```
randomVar = random.sample([var1, var2, var3, var4], 1)
```

**Which gives me this result:**

```
[[[0.09476800262928009, -0.23948000371456146, 0.22791500389575958], 
  [0.015838999301195145, 0.2482910007238388, 0.16062000393867493]]]
```

**But I need this:**

```
[[0.09476800262928009, -0.23948000371456146, 0.22791500389575958],
 [0.015838999301195145, 0.2482910007238388, 0.16062000393867493]]
```

The reckon the answer to this will be pretty easy, but I failed to find a solution for this so far. Still pretty new to scripting so forgive me if I overlooked an obvious solution.

Comment: randomVar = random.sample([var1, var2, var3, var4], 1)[0]

Wont that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
randomVar = random.choice([var1,var2,var3,var4])
```

This will produce the result you want.

**Example output:**

```
>>> print randomVar

[[0.09476800262928009, -0.23948000371456146, 0.22791500389575958], 
 [0.015838999301195145, 0.2482910007238388, 0.16062000393867493]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 randomVar = random.sample([var1, var2, var3, var4], 1)[0]
```